# Getting 0 in ajax response wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have created a plugin for user to check delivery option is available in their location or not.
backend code is working fine like, I can add zipcode. data is showing in the admin table.
in the frontend am trying to check data via ajax call where getting response as 0 with if statement even when I enter an existing zip code or wrong.
Please help where am wrong. Thanks.

**Here is JavaScript Ajax Code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var zipcodeInput = jQuery("#checkzipcode").find("input[name='checkzipcode']");
var zipcodeSubmit = jQuery("#ajax-form");
zipcodeSubmit.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: my_action_callback.ajaxurl,
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            action: 'my_action_callback',
            checkzipcode: zipcodeInput.val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            jQuery('#zipcode-result').html(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
});
});
```

**Here is THML Code**

```
function check_zipcode_for_delivery_frontend(){ ?>
    <div class="woo-zcd-form">
        <form method="POST" id="ajax-form">
            <label>Enter Zipcode:</label>
            <input type="text" name="checkzipcode" id="checkzipcode" required>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check Zipcode" id="submit-zipcode">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="zipcode-result"></div>

<?php }

add_shortcode('check_zipcode_delivery', 'check_zipcode_for_delivery_frontend');
```

**Here is PHP Code**

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/js/custom.js', array('jquery') );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
  wp_localize_script( 'my_custom_script', 'my_action_callback', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ) );
});


add_action('wp_ajax_my_action_callback', 'my_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action_callback', 'my_action_callback');

function my_action_callback() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "deliverybyzipcode";
    $checkzipcode = $_POST['checkzipcode'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$table_name." WHERE delivery_zipcode = '$checkzipcode'";

    $result = $wpdb->query($sql);
    $rows = $result->num_rows;
    if($rows == $checkzipcode) {
        echo "Yes! Our delivery service is available in your area.";
    }
    else {
        echo 'Sorry! we are currently no delivering in your area.';
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by inspecting the request itself in dev tools network tab and see if url and data sent are as expected , status and response body etc so you can narrow down where problem is

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is causing the trouble.

Change this line `$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$table_name." WHERE delivery_zipcode = '$checkzipcode'";`

to this one `$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$table_name." WHERE delivery_zipcode = '".$checkzipcode."'";`

It is not clear from your question what is the type of delivery_code in your database so you should pay attention to that as well. And of course, take care of SQL injection.